# An error in Haskell pattern matching

Tags: haskell

This is one of my lab question, I have to write a `maybeDiv` function, and here is my work. There is an error in `Just x y`, May I ask what causes this error? Thanks.

```
maybeDiv :: Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer
maybeDiv mx my = case mx my of
    Just x y
      | y == 0 -> Just Nothing
      | otherwise -> Just (x / y)
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

Comment: This is totally out of syntax...

Comment: `mx`, `Just x` aren't functions.

Comment: And `Just Nothing` has not type `Maybe Integer`.

Comment: `x/y` is not an integer in general. Or do you want the quotient of the Euclidean division ?

Comment: `x / y` doesn't even type check, even if `x` and `y` are both integers. You want `div` instead.

Comment: This is probably not what your lab instructor expects or wants, but you might want to look up the `liftA2` function found in `Control.Applicative`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program should rather looks like:

```
maybeDiv :: Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer
maybeDiv mx my = case (mx, my) of
    (Just x, Just y)
      | y == 0 -> Nothing
      | otherwise -> Just (x / y)
    _ -> Nothing
```

My PC is currently busy with doing a huge animation so I cannot check. I'll check later unless someone corrects me before.

But that will not work because `x/y` is not an Integer. You should rather want a `Double`. So:

```
maybeDiv :: Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer -> Maybe Double
maybeDiv mx my = case (mx, my) of
    (Just x, Just y)
      | y == 0 -> Nothing
      | otherwise -> Just (fromInteger x / fromInteger y)
    _ -> Nothing
```

### Edit

If you are not allowed to use the 2-tuple `(mx,my)`, as you said in a comment, you can do:

```
maybeDiv :: Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer -> Maybe Double
maybeDiv mx my =
  case my of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just 0  -> Nothing
    Just y  -> case mx of
      Nothing -> Nothing
      Just x  -> Just (fromInteger x / fromInteger y)
```

If you want the quotient of the Euclidean division as the output, do:

```
maybeDiv :: Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer
maybeDiv mx my =
  case my of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just 0  -> Nothing
    Just y  -> case mx of
      Nothing -> Nothing
      Just x  -> Just (x `quot` y)
```

You could also generalize the function in order that it accepts `Integer` and `Int` types, like this:

```
maybeDiv :: Integral a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
maybeDiv mx my =
  case my of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just 0  -> Nothing
    Just y  -> case mx of
      Nothing -> Nothing
      Just x  -> Just (x `quot` y)
```

Comment: Oops sorry, `x/y`  is not `Integer`... that will not work. I will delete my answer.

Comment: Maybe the asker intended `quot`...?

Comment: Thanks, the type declaration is set by the Lab instruction and we have not learnt (x,y) yet.

Comment: @Tony And what is the output desired by the lab ? The quotient of the Euclidean division ?

Comment: Thanks again, this will help. I just need the general function but I can learn the format from the quotient function as well.

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent the lab asked only for general function of division,thanks for help. actually the function can also be written by guards, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is for a lab, you might not be allowed to use Applicative - however, for the sake of clarity, here's what your function could/should actually be:

```
maybeDiv :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
maybeDiv ma mb = quot <$> ma <*> mb
```

This will end up equivalent to the other answers, but might be a lot cleaner to read.